# Which characters to escape to match these in find regex expression in Bourne shell?

Tags: regex, find, sh

I writing a little bourne shell script which load a conf file content a string, this string is uses in find (after some awk tricks) like this following example:

original string:

```
rx='~ #'
```

find command:

```
find -regex "^.*~$\|^.*#$"
```

EDIT: the original string is in a conf file, so the problem is when the string content special characters as "*.".. Exemple:

original string (with characters to escape):

```
rx='~ # $*'
```

EDIT2:  I trying to match any file ended by word in rx (separates with space). If rx="st ar", I want to match with "test" and "bar". But if the word content any characters as * $, my regex doesn't work properly.. So, I wanted to know which is all characters that I have to escape to make it work..
Thank's ! :)

Comment: Are you trying to match files ending in `~` or `#`? You don't have to escape any characters (other than the `|` you are already escaping.

Comment: Sorry, I have not been clear.. Yes, that what I try, but it's not the current problem. I wanted to ask which characters I have to escape in the original string (the string can change, it can content * or $ for example) and make it work with these character?

Comment: How is the original string used? Do you mean you load a string from the file and use that as the argument to `-regex`? (`rx=$(...); find -regex "$rx"`)

Comment: Yes, I have a conf file with `rx='# ~'` or `rx='$ *'`, etc.. I use source to load the file, I transform my string with awk, which give `rx='^.*~$\|^.*#$'` then I recover the content of `find -regex "$rx"`

Comment: I think you're ok then, nothing else needs to be escaped. (The single quotes protect everything in the original, and you are properly quoting everything when you pass the string to `-regex`.

Comment: Not really, If my init string is `rx='~ $|^.**$'`, doesn't match with any file its end with "$|^.**$" (ok, it's strange but I want to make it really safe.. ^^).
In fact, even if `rx='# *'`, my awk command match with all file (which is `echo "$rx" | awk '{ gsub(" ", "$\\|^.*", $0); print "^.*"$0"$" }'` )

Comment: Are you trying to match a file named `~ #`? It's not at all clear to me what the question entails.

Comment: I fix * problem (my bad)..
So what is " special characters" that interact in a find regex ? :/ Sorry if i'm not clear.. :/

Comment: Also, when you say Bourne, do you really mean Bourne (70s-era shell, only shipped in recent decades as part of SunOS), or do you mean POSIX sh (90s-era standard followed by modern `/bin/sh` implementations such as ash, dash, etc., and of which bash, ksh, &c. are a superset)?

Comment: Hint: If `echo ^ echo` prints only an empty line it's Bourne shell; if it prints a single line of output with `^ echo` as literal content, it's POSIX sh.

Comment: BTW, if you want to treat your name as literal, why use `-regex` at all?

Comment: I mean POSIX sh.

No, I trying to match any file ended by word in rx (separates with space). If `rx="st ar"`, I want to match with "test" and "bar". But if the word content any characters as * $, my regex doesn't work properly.. So, I wanted to know which is all characters that I have to escape to make it work.. I don't know how explain better, sorry.. :/

Comment: Ahh! That's a good enough explanation, thank you.

Comment: Hmm. The idiom I'd usually use for the safe string-splitting is a bashism.

Comment: Thank's, I edit the first post to make it clear for any one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to split your string on spaces, and match any substring from that split.

The irc.freenode.org #bash channel [has a factoid providing a function for performing quoting](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/requote), used below with some minor tweaks for POSIX compatibility:

```
requote() { printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g'; }

input_string='hello# cruel*world how~are~you'
output_string=$(printf '%s\n' "$input_string" | tr ' ' '\n' | {
  out_s=''
  while read -r line; do
    if [ -n "$out_s" ]; then
      out_s="${out_s}|$(requote "$line")"
    else
      out_s="$(requote "$line")"
    fi
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$out_s"
})

find . -regex ".*(${output_string}).*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank's to Charles Duffy, I understand that the good method is to encapsule any characters in "[]" to make there safe in a regex. Except for '^', we make it like this '\^'. here's what I did bases on the answer of Mr. Duffy.

So, I have an init string and I want to match with any words in this string.

Init string (emacs tmp and example for this trick)

```
rx=' ~   #   oo    ^  '
```

First, I trim the strign like this:

```
rx=`printf '%s\n' "$rx" | awk '{$1=$1};1'`
```

`==> rx='~ # oo ^'`

Second, I do the sed trick of Duffy with some change to apply in my case:

```
rx=`printf '%s\n' "$rx" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/ /g; s/[^^ ]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g'`;

==> rx='[~] [#] [oo] [^]'
```

Third, I apply a little awk command to make a regex:

```
rx=`printf '%s\n' "$rx" | awk '{ gsub(" ", "$\\|^.*", $0); print "^.*"$0"$" }'`;

==> rx='^.*[~]$\|^.*[#]$\|^.*[o][o]$\|^.*\^$'
```

Finally, I just exec my find command like this:

```
find -regex "$rx"
```

et voilà !

BTW, i'm doing this:

```
rx=`printf '%s\n' "$rx" | awk '{$1=$1};1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/ /g; s/[^^ ]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' | awk '{ gsub(" ", "$\\|^.*", $0);'
```

Comment: Oops! Was missing some parens needed to make my solution work just as it was; feel a bit bad about that, but glad you got everything working!

Comment: BTW, `<<<` is not available in POSIX sh, so if you want to be portable, you should consider taking that out; there's a reason I used `printf '%s\n' | ...`.

Comment: Similarly, if you need to be compatible to all POSIX shells, using `echo` is a bad portability decision: The standard gives `echo` implementations many decisions about how to behave, and some of them will munge your data in ways you don't want. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: Ho ! Thank's for your advice :)

Comment: I just have a little issue..
`print '%s\n' '*'` that will print all fille in my current directory... :/ How can I fix it ?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '*'`, **with quotes**, should not do that; that's what you'd get from `printf '%s\n' *`, without the quotes on the `*`. Can you provide a line you've tested to reproduce the case when run standing alone?

Comment: Note that `var='*'` and then `printf '%s\n' $var` is the same as using your `*` unquoted; you need to use `printf '%s\n' "$var"` (with the double quotes) to ensure that the expansion is not string-split and globbed.

Comment: My bad, it's because I'm doing like this:
`function my_print() {
printf '%s\n' '*'
}

rx=`my_print`
printf '%s\n' "$rx"`

Comment: that alone shouldn't cause the problem -- I'd need to see the inside of the function body. BTW, the `function` keyword is another bash extension, not compatible with the POSIX sh specification; the POSIX-compatible way to specify a function is `print() {`, as opposed to `function print {`.

Comment: Thank you for your edits, but I still can't reproduce the issue; the following works perfectly: `my_print() { printf '%s\n' '*'; }; rx=$(my_print); printf '%s\n' "$rx"`

Comment: I edit my last comment, thank's again for POSIX advice :)
I'm good know, thank you for everything !

Comment: Correction: `printf '%s\n' $rx` and not `printf '%s\n' "$rx"`, my bad again.. I was too fast I guess.. ^^'

Comment: Ahh. Yup, that explains it; glad I could help. :)